# how to handle events in nested recursive component

Tags: angular, recursion, angular2-template

I'm trying to build a tree component where `od-tree-node` component is nested recursively to build child nodes. I'm having problem with handling events. 
For click events on the leaf node, the mouse event always triggers as if the event occurred on the the top most component. I'm not sure how to handle this.

The expected behavior: When the user clicks on leaf/parent/root node the parent component (ex: `app.component.ts`) needs to know what node was clicked.

Current behavior: No matter which node is clicked, the root node is selected (emitted to parent component)

**plunker**: https://plnkr.co/edit/JZTlA5?p=preview

Here's the template:

**node.component.html**

```
<!-- parent node -->
<label [attr.for]="resource.resourceType" [class]="cssClasses" *ngIf="resource.hasChildren()" [hidden]="matchedChildrenCount(search, resource) === 0">
     <a (click)="toggleNode($event)"> <i [class]="getNodeStateIcon()"></i></a>
     <input type="checkbox" *ngIf="showCheckboxes" [checked]="selected">
     <a [title]="resource.resourceName" (click)="selectNode($event);">
        <i [class]="resource.getIcon()"></i> {{resource.resourceName}} | {{ matchedChildrenCount(search, resource) | lpad : 2 : '0'}}
     </a>
</label>
<!-- leaf node -->
<label [attr.for]="resource.resourceType" [class]="cssClasses" *ngIf="!resource.hasChildren()" [hidden]="!isMatched(search, resource)">
     <input type="checkbox" *ngIf="showCheckboxes" [checked]="selected">
     <a [title]="resource.resourceName" (click)="selectNode($event);">
        <i class="icon-status-indicator"></i> {{resource.resourceName}}
        <div class="group" *ngIf="resource?.group !== 'Default'">{{resource.group}}</div>
     </a>
</label>
<!-- recrusive child nodes -->
<ul *ngIf="resource.expanded">
  <li *ngFor="let child of resource?.children">
    <od-tree-node
      [resource]="child"
      [search]="search"
      (selected)="selectNode($event)"
      ></od-tree-node>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**node.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'od-tree-node',
    templateUrl: 'node.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['node.component.css'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class NodeComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
  @Input() resource: TreeNode;

  @Output() selected = new EventEmitter<TreeNode>();

  cssClasses: string;

  /**
   * select/unselect node
   *
   */
  selectNode(event: MouseEvent) {
    if(event instanceof MouseEvent) {
         event.preventDefault();
         event.stopPropagation();
      }
    this.resource.selected = true;
    this.cssClasses = this.setCssClasses();
    this.selected.emit(this.resource);
  }
 ...
 ....
 ....
}
```

Comment: You're saying `event.stopPropagation()` is not working?

Comment: Yes. I'm really stumped.

Comment: Is the `if(event instanceof MouseEvent)` test really necessary?

Comment: Yes, I added because of the problem in question. Because of the nested template, `selected` event gets TreeNode component instead of MouseEvent object due to event bubbling

Comment: I think a Plunker would be helpful to investigate.

Comment: ok, let me try to create one

Comment: I can reproduce the issue here [https://plnkr.co/edit/JZTlA5?p=preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/JZTlA5?p=preview)

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what you expect. Your `selectNode()` event handler propagates the event to the next node up to the root node. If you don't want that, then don't do it. What is the expected behavior?

Comment: I don't want do it. How do I NOT do it ? My brain is hot mess right now.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer could you please show how its done?. Please note that I want to be able to select leaf/parent/root nodes, not just leaf node.

Comment: So why do you foreard select events to parent? I need to know what exactly is the expected behavior.

Comment: The objective is this: The tree component will be hosted inside a parent component (ex: `app.component.ts`). When the user clicks on leaf/parent/root node the parent component needs to know what node was clicked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case every node is sending itself to its parent and thus app component always get root node of the tree. Solution is that in case of click event send that node itself to the parent node else just pass on what is received from eventemitter of child node.

```
selectNode(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log(event)
    let selNode: any;
    if(event instanceof MouseEvent) {
         event.preventDefault();
         event.stopPropagation();
         selNode = this.resource
    } else {
        selNode = event
    }
    this.selected.emit(selNode);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! thats exactly what I wanted.